# unexpected behavior when use $setPristine()

Tags: angularjs

There is some unexpected behavior occurring in my project when $setPristine() is added to a function.

Here is the code for the 2 relevant input boxes in the HTML template that appear in screenshots below:

```html
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$invalid}">
                            <label for="FatA" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fat A</label>
                            <input name="FatA" type="text" class="form-control col-sm-10 input-sm" ng-required="true" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ui-validate="{numberCheck: 'vm.numberCheck($value)', fatRangeCheck: 'vm.fatRangeCheck($value)', decimalCheck: 'vm.decimalCheck($value)'}" ng-model="vm.formulaInput.Fats[0]" /><span>%</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$invalid">Invalid entry.</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$error.numberCheck">{{vm.errorMessages.numberCheck}}</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$error.fatRangeCheck">{{vm.errorMessages.fatRangeCheck}}</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatA.$error.decimalCheck">{{vm.errorMessages.decimalCheck}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$invalid}">
                            <label for="FatB" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fat B</label>
                                <input name="FatB" type="text" class="form-control col-sm-10 input-sm" ng-required="true" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ui-validate="{numberCheck: 'vm.numberCheck($value)', fatRangeCheck: 'vm.fatRangeCheck($value)', decimalCheck: 'vm.decimalCheck($value)'}" ng-model="vm.formulaInput.Fats[1]" /><span>%</span>
                                <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$invalid">Invalid entry.</span>
                                <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$error.numberCheck">{{vm.errorMessages.numberCheck}}</span>
                                <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$error.fatRangeCheck">{{vm.errorMessages.fatRangeCheck}}</span>
                                <span class="error" ng-show="vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$dirty && vm.formContainer.form.FatB.$error.decimalCheck">{{vm.errorMessages.decimalCheck}}</span>
                        </div>
```

Here is the code for the Clear button and the 2 elements that show what's in the model for "formula input" and "formula results":

```html
<input type="reset" value="Clear" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.clear()" ng-disabled="vm.formContainer.form.$pristine" />

<div>formula input: {{vm.formulaInput}}</div>
<div>formula results: {{vm.formulaResults}}</div>
```

Here is the clear function in the JS file:

```js
        vm.clear = function () {            
            vm.formulaInput = {};
            vm.formulaInput.Fats = [];
            vm.formulaResults = null;            
        }
```

If a user enters letters instead of a number in either input box then a validation error is supposed to appear like so:
[image]

That part is working correctly.

However, when the user clicks Clear, and the clear function in the JS is as shown above, the form shows that both input boxes have invalid entries:
[image]

This is not the desired thing to show after the user clicks Clear.  What is supposed to be shown is the blank form without any validation errors so the user can start over again.  In an attempt to fix this issue $setPristine() was added to the clear function:

```js
        vm.clear = function () {            
            vm.formulaInput = {};
            vm.formulaInput.Fats = [];
            vm.formulaResults = null;
            vm.formContainer.form.$setPristine();
        }
```

Say the user enters the same values as above:
[image]

Now when the user clicks Clear the validation errors disappear, which is good, but the invalid entry does not clear out of the input box:

[image]

By looking at the "formula input" element I have noticed that the Fats array shows a null in place of the letters that were entered in the input box.  Perhaps that is a pertinent piece of this issue...?

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you. The posted code doesn't run. For example, where is declared `formContainer`? Maybe, create a JSFiddle or similar?

Comment: @lealceldeiro Being new to jsfiddle and AngularJS I'm having some difficulty getting the basic example to work.  Here's what's out there so far: http://jsfiddle.net/csLx37nr/17/  Why doesn't it work?